# пустые значения в count

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, count

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`SQL Server`
В отчете,который обращается к таблицам,содержащим одинаковые колонки `AFFECTED_ITEM` и `SUBCATEGORY`, должны выводить `Count` по `Affected_item`
В результате у меня появляются пустые значения некоторых местах.
Если значение услуги везде 0,то не выводить его.

```
SELECT
   t.AFFECTED_ITEM,
   t.SUBCATEGORY,
   Table1,
   Table2,
   Table3
FROM (
SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM  [dbo].[CM3RM1]
UNION
SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM [dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]
UNION
SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY FROM  [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1]

) t
LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, count(*) as Table1 from [dbo].[CM3RM1] WHERE  AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
group by AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY  HAVING  COUNT(AFFECTED_ITEM) > 0) as t1 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t1.AFFECTED_ITEM AND t.SUBCATEGORY = t1.SUBCATEGORY


LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, count(*) as Table2 from [dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]  WHERE   AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
group by AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY  HAVING  COUNT(AFFECTED_ITEM) > 0) as t2 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t2.AFFECTED_ITEM AND t.SUBCATEGORY = t2.SUBCATEGORY



LEFT JOIN (select AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, count(*) as Table3 from [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] WHERE   AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
group by AFFECTED_ITEM , SUBCATEGORY  HAVING  COUNT(AFFECTED_ITEM) > 0) as t3 ON t.AFFECTED_ITEM = t3.AFFECTED_ITEM AND t.SUBCATEGORY = t3.SUBCATEGORY



WHERE t.AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL AND t.SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

Comment: А что должно быть на месте пустых значений ? И  кстати, зачем условие `having  COUNT(AFFECTED_ITEM)>0` при условии `AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL` count() заведомо больше нуля, если бы он был 0 то такой строки в выборке бы по любому не появилось

Comment: если значения во всех колонках пустые,то не выводить совсем

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю упростить запрос до такого:

```
SELECT t.AFFECTED_ITEM,
       t.SUBCATEGORY,
       sum(T1) as Table1,
       sum(T2) as Table2,
       sum(T3) as Table3
  FROM (
    SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, 1 as T1, 0 as T2, 0 as T3
      FROM  [dbo].[CM3RM1]
     WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
   UNION ALL
    SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, 0 as T1, 1 as T2, 0 as T3
      FROM [dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]
     WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
   UNION ALL
    SELECT AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY, 0 as T1, 0 as T2, 1 as T3
      FROM  [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1]
     WHERE AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL  and SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL 
  ) t
 GROUP BY AFFECTED_ITEM, SUBCATEGORY
```

Если в таблицах заведомо не может быть строк с NULL в `AFFECTED_ITEM` или `SUBCATEGORY` (а я подозреваю, что это так и есть) - то условия `where` можно опустить

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит, потому как во вложенных запросах вы отбрасываете значения с нулями  `HAVING COUNT(AFFECTED_ITEM) > 0`. Но даже если вы уберете `HAVING`, не факт что нули появятся, так как в любой из таблиц может отсутствовать пара `AFFECTED_ITEM` и `SUBCATEGORY` и при этом быть в другой.

Вам поможет добавить `ISNULL` в выводе:

```
SELECT
   t.AFFECTED_ITEM,
   t.SUBCATEGORY,
   Table1 = ISNULL(Table1, 0),
   Table2 = ISNULL(Table2, 0),
   Table3 = ISNULL(Table3, 0)
FROM (
...
WHERE t.AFFECTED_ITEM IS NOT NULL AND t.SUBCATEGORY IS NOT NULL
     AND NOT (Table1 IS NULL AND Table2 IS NULL AND Table3 IS NULL)
ORDER BY t.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

**UPD** Добавил условие для скрытия строк с пустыми значениями.

Comment: теперь в выводе нули появились, а мне необходимо,чтобы пустые нулевые значения вообще не выводились

Comment: @keilash тогда добавьте условие в where запроса `(Table1 is not null OR Table2 is not null OR Table3 is not null)`

Comment: @keilash добавил дополнительное условие.